# Using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with Spring OAuth2 and user-info-uri

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have created an Authorization service as follows

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationApplication {
   ...
}
```

With this `application.properties`.

```
server.port=9000
security.oauth2.client.client-id=monederobingo
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=monederobingosecret
security.oauth2.client.authorized-grant-types=authorization_code,refresh_token,password,client_credentials
security.oauth2.client.scope=company,client
```

Then, in a separate spring boot project I have created a Resource Server.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class App {
   ...
}
```

With this `application.properties`.

```
server.port=9090
spring.application.name=app
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:9000/user
```

Now, everything works fine if I send a request like this `localhost:9090/api` with the appropriate token that was retrieved by Authorization Service.

However, I don't want to send this token when sending requests to `localhost:9090/login`.

For this I have created this class in my Resource server spring boot app.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated();
    }

}
```

And now I don't need to send any token to send a request to `/login`.

However, I'm now geting the following message when sending request to `/api` with a valid token.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1496027102659,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Access Denied",
  "path": "/api/v1/points_configuration/314"
}
```

How can configure security for only a few URL patterns in Spring Security OAuth2?

Comment: Add  .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated(); in your resource server configuration, and try again

Comment: @Afridi I already have that in `SpringConfig` class.

Comment: I am not talking about WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extended class. Extends your 'App' class from ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter and then override this method:
@Override
 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**") .authenticated();
}

Comment: @That worked. Could you please add that as Answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Also, why did this work by using `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` instead of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Kindly follow this for more info regarding Spring OAuth security:[Secure Spring REST Api with OAuth](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/)***

In order to implement OAuth Security in Spring boot, you have to create Authorization & Resource server by extending them from `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` respectively.

### Authorization Server

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationApplication extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore()).approvalStoreDisabled();
        }

       @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.withClientDetails(mongoClientDetailsService);
            /*inMemory()
                    .withClient(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_CLIENTID))
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token","client_credentials")
                    .secret(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_SECRET))
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(propertyResolver.getProperty(PROP_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS, Integer.class, 18000));*/
        }

//Do others stuff
    }
```

### Resource Server

All the Url that you want to protect using OAuth should be mentioned in this server configuration. It enables a Spring Security filter that authenticates requests using an incoming OAuth2 token. While mostly `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` extended class is used for basic security configuration like adding filters, allowing un-secure url or implementing session policies etc.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class App extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
}
  //Do others stuff
}
```

Comment: userDetailsService(userDetailsService)  is not available in **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter**

Comment: @wildthing81 I used `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)` not `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.**`

`endpoints.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)...`

Comment: my bad...I meant **AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer**. the method doesn't exist

Comment: This helps me. Thanks